# How to update a list when using for loops in python

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, append

Im am making a program that is designed to solve word searches using functions. The output I get from the function find_horizontal 
is:

`['********RRIRAI', 'FUNCTIONRRIRAI', 'RAIOONFRCCPWON', 'PTCSNOBEUITOLO', 'BNCACIANTOSLIH', 'RBYOLILYNREFBT', 'HYYNOGESTIBRIY', 'AATTSIONCMCENP', 'UORTENRRCBFVAU', 'CEBEECVWIERORI', '*********TOPYF', 'PROCESSORTOPYF', 'OH********HSOS', 'OHCOMPUTERHSOS', 'YCYPRESREOSMRW', 'OATHBRMVTHHCTR', 'PGORWOOUIPSCHP']`

The problem is that it has added the line to the list Outpuz once with the found word crossed out and then secondly before it was crossed out. My desired output is:

`['********RRIRAI', 'RAIOONFRCCPWON', 'PTCSNOBEUITOLO', 'BNCACIANTOSLIH', 'RBYOLILYNREFBT', 'HYYNOGESTIBRIY', 'AATTSIONCMCENP', 'UORTENRRCBFVAU', 'CEBEECVWIERORI', '*********TOPYF', 'OH********HSOS', 'YCYPRESREOSMRW', 'OATHBRMVTHHCTR', 'PGORWOOUIPSCHP']`

Here is my full code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Puzzle = ["FUNCTIONRRIRAI",
              "RAIOONFRCCPWON",
              "PTCSNOBEUITOLO",
              "BNCACIANTOSLIH",
              "RBYOLILYNREFBT",
              "HYYNOGESTIBRIY",
              "AATTSIONCMCENP",
              "UORTENRRCBFVAU",
              "CEBEECVWIERORI",
              "PROCESSORTOPYF",
              "OHCOMPUTERHSOS",
              "YCYPRESREOSMRW",
              "OATHBRMVTHHCTR",
              "PGORWOOUIPSCHP"]


def load_words_to_find(file_name):
    word_list = []
    file = open(file_name, "r")
    for line in file.readlines():
        word_list.append(line)
    word_list = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), word_list))
    return word_list


def find_horizontal(Puzzle, Words, ReplaceWith, Found):
    # Parameters :- List:Puzzle, List:Words, Character:ReplaceWith, List:Found
    # Return :- List:Outpuz, List:Found
    # Find all words which are horizontally in place (left to right and right to left), return the puzzle and list of found words
    add = True
    Outpuz = []
    for line in Puzzle:
        for word in Words:
            if word in line:
                Found.append(word)
                print("Found: ", word)
                Outpuz.append(line.replace(word,ReplaceWith*len(word)))
                add = False
        if not add:
            pass
        elif add:
            Outpuz.append(line)


        Outpuz.append(line)
    print(Outpuz)

    return Outpuz, Found


find_horizontal(Puzzle, load_words_to_find("words.txt"), "*", [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar about a year ago.

https://github.com/BenMcLean981/Python-Wordsearch

I think the issue is Outpuz.append(line) is just adding every line from puzzle to output.

What is in your filename? What is found and Outpuz supposed to be? Found I guess is the list of word from words that it has found in puzzle. But then whats outpuz?

Id change it from this:

```
if word in line:
    Found.append(word)
    print("Found: ", word)
    Outpuz.append(line.replace(word,ReplaceWith*len(word)))
    add = False
if not add:
    pass
elif add:
    Outpuz.append(line)
Outpuz.append(line


Outpuz.append(line)
```

to this:

```
if word in line:
    Found.append(word)
    print("Found: ", word)
    Outpuz.append(line.replace(word,ReplaceWith*len(word)))
    #Adds the line if it has the change
else:
    Outpuz.append(line) #Adds the line if it doesnt have the change.
```

Comment: I am unsure by what you mean by what is in your file name, could you clarify please? You are correct about found and Outpuz is suppose to be the updated word search (It is for college home work and my teacher has designed code to self mark it for him so i cannot change the return names so im assuming its that updated word search)

Comment: See my edit, new to stack overflow so not really sure if I'm using it right.

Comment: I changed my code so now if the if it is found it adds it to Outpuz but if its not found (if word not in line/else) the  add the line but it still add the line even when found: